# Wrapping of high capacity (HC) counters

Tags: ethernet, snmp, management

Am I correct that HC SNMP interface counters like `ifHCInOctets`/`ifHCOutOctets` or `ifHCInUcastPkts`/`ifHCOutUcastPkts` wrap after such a long period that applications using those counters do not need to take this wrapping into account (not including situations where the counters might reset such as a switch reloading).

For example, even if 100GigE interface is fully utilized 24/7, the counter would wrap after 46 years and 9 months:

```
$ echo "((2^64-1)/(100*10^9/8))/60/60/24/365" | bc -l
46.79539338840576259512
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Need to**? Not in a day-to-day sense, but you're going to have some serious unhappy customers if your widget fails to deal with it properly. There are plenty of examples of "*shouldn't happen*" events programmers ignore that *do* happen and breaks all kinds of things. (you if you're Tivo, the system crashes/panics/etc.)

(I know, one cannot program for every possibility, but this isn't one of those times. Counter overflows / resets WILL happen; be prepared for it.)

Comment: I understand. However, strictly the counter wrap of a 64 bit counter will happen in 46.795 years in case of 100GigE interface?

Comment: It is an event that will happen *per design*, ignore it at your peril

Answer (score -4):

An SNMP object defined as a Counter must abide by [RFC1155](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1155.txt):

"3.2.3.3. Counter

This application-wide type represents a non-negative integer which monotonically increases until it reaches a maximum value, when it wraps around and starts increasing again from zero. This memo specifies a maximum value of 2^32-1 (4294967295 decimal) for counters."

Comment: "HC" counters are 64 bit.  See RFC 2233 (3.1.6)

Comment: The wrapping behavior is established in 1155.

Comment: ifHC* are *Counter64* not *Counter* (or *Counter32* these days)